# how to get thymeleaf variable from public source file

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to learn **thymeleaf** i got stuck on this issue and i couldn't solve it.

In javascript, if i want to pull thymeleaf variable i simply need to do

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
...code
 $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/doctors/en/resetPassword?t='+/*[[${token}]]*/,
```

But what if i have a code in external javascript file? i'm unable to know if i can add thymeleaf xlmns to `.js` file,

if i add `/*[[${token}]]*/` to another java script file it will be commented.

so what should i do ?

Note that i need to pull the response comming from ajax not for doing the ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass thymeleaf variable to a function:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    getVariable([[${token}]]);

    /*]]>*/

</script>
```

Comment: i dont want to use `th:inline`

Comment: For use thymeleaf variable in javascript you should use `th:inline`